# How to vectorize 2 loops in R

Tags: r, performance, vectorization

I have two matrices:

```
matr1 = [k ; n]
matr2 = [n ; m]
```

and a vector `x`. `length(x) = k`
Vector `x` contains values `1 : m`

```
n = 5
m = 3
k = m * n

matr1 <- matrix(sample(seq(0,1, by = 0.1), size = k * n, replace = T), nrow = k, ncol = n )
matr2 <- matrix(sample(seq(0,1, by = 0.1), size = m * n, replace = T), nrow = n, ncol = m)
x <- sample(1:m, size = k, replace = T)
```

I have to perform the following operation, which I solved using `for` loops.

```
for( i in 1:k){
  for( j in 1:n){
    matr1[i, 1:(n-j+1)] <- matr1[i, 1:(n-j+1)] + 
      matr1[i, 1:(n-j+1)] * matr2[j , x[i]]
  }
}
```

Is there a way to vectorise it somehow?

Or maybe use some techniques to speed up the calculation?

P.S. I considered using basic parallelization, but I want to find more clever ways

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide two sample matrices to run your code

Comment: `apply` functions are usually better and more readable when it comes to evaluating functions.

Comment: forgot to mention, that vector `x` contains values from 1 to m

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and then, please add all the rest of the stuff you forgot to mention.

Comment: @VadymB. If you notice that you forgot something, please edit it into the question, and not just mention it in a comment. As others have said already, you should add example data for x, matr1 and matr2 to your post.

Comment: You could avoid the `1:k` loop: `for(j in seq_len(n)) matr1[, seq_len(n - j + 1)] = matr1[, seq_len(n - j + 1)] + matr1[, seq_len(n - j + 1)] * matr2[cbind(j, x)]`. How large are "k" and "n" relative to each other? You could, also, save `matr1[, seq_len(n - j + 1)]` to a temporary variable to avoid re-subsetting "matr1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me a while to figure out, but:

```
foo <- apply(matr2,2,function(x) rev(cumprod(x+1)))
matr3 <- matr1*t(foo[,x])
```

**-- PROOF --**

```
set.seed(100)
n = 5
m = 3
k = m * n

matr1 <- matrix(sample(seq(0,1, by = 0.1), size = k * n, replace = T), nrow = k, ncol = n )
matr2 <- matrix(sample(seq(0,1, by = 0.1), size = m * n, replace = T), nrow = n, ncol = m)
x <- sample(1:m, size = k, replace = T)

foo <- apply(matr2,2,function(x) rev(cumprod(x+1)))
matr3 <- matr1*t(foo[,x])

for( i in 1:k){
  for( j in 1:n){
    matr1[i, 1:(n-j+1)] <- matr1[i, 1:(n-j+1)] + 
      matr1[i, 1:(n-j+1)] * matr2[j , x[i]]
  }
}

all.equal(matr3,matr1)
# TRUE
```

**-- EXPLANATION --**

So it took me a while to figure this out correctly, but here goes... Assuming your code and assuming `i = 1`, we can basically write for `j=1`:

```
matr1[1,1:5] <- matr1[1,1:5] + matr1[1,1:5] * matr2[1,3]
```

So you take row 1, columns 1 to 5, and you update these numbers with the original number PLUS those numbers times some other number (in this case `0.8`). Then, when `j=2`:

```
matr1[1,1:4] <- matr1[1,1:4] + matr1[1,1:4] * matr2[2,3]
```

So now you only take all columns but `n` itself, and update the value in the same way as step 1. In the end, the pattern that should be clear is that `matr1[1,1]` is updated `n` times, whereas `matr[1,n]` is updated `1` time (with only `matr2[1,3]`.

We exploit this pattern by pre-calculating all steps in one go. We do that with:

```
foo <- apply(matr2,2,function(x) rev(cumprod(x+1)))
```

This basically is a new table that contains, for each column of `matr1[i,]`, a number. This number is a combination of all loops that your previous code ran into a single number. So, instead of `matr1[1,1]` requiring 5 multiplications, we now just do 1.

So now we have:

```
for (i in 1:k) for (j in 1:n) matr1[i,j] <- matr1[i,j] * foo[j,x[i]]
```

We can reduce that to:

```
for (i in 1:k) matr1[i,] <- matr1[i,] * foo[,x[i]]
```

Since `i` always goes from `1:k` for every single time you index it, we can just vectorize that as well:

```
matr <- matr*t(foo[,x])
```

And we're done.

**-- BENCHMARK --**

I reran the code block that I gave as a proof, but with `n=100` and `m=100`.

Your code:

```
# user  system elapsed 
# 6.85    0.00    6.86
```

My code:

```
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.02    0.00    0.02
```

Comment: Your idea is great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your double loop, you could `apply` over a k-n-grid.

```
suppressOutput <- apply(expand.grid(1:k, 1:n), 1, function(y){
    matr1[y[1], 1:(n-y[2]+1)] <<- matr1[y[1], 1:(n-y[2]+1)] + matr1[y[1], 1:(n-y[2]+1)] * matr2[y[2] , x[y[1]]]
})
```

Saves over 50% calc time on my machine. It's not very pretty though.

Comment: You forgot to substitute one `j`: `matr1[i, 1:(n-j+1)] <<-`

Comment: Of course, because it is smarter programming to begin with.